# Visual Studio 2010 extension for generating C++ code?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, auto-generate

I've been spending all day trying to figure out if it's possible for VS2010 to generate a code template using variables. I'm taking a C++ class wanted to avoid copy/pasting each time I create a new CPP file. I was just looking at doing it for a simple win32 console app so it's just once cpp file. Is this even possible with VS2010?

```
/**
    @file <Filename>
    @author <Name>
    @date <Date>
    @version 1.0
*/

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks,
LF4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to achieve what you want by creating a project and then use the Export Template Wizard to turn your project into a project template.  You can also create a project template manually.  You can read more about project templates [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s365byhx.aspx).

For more elaborate templates you can create a [Visual C++ Custom Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xz4cw2.aspx).

Comment: Oh thank you that helped a lot I didn't know I could create a custom wizard.